# 931107 - configuring squid

Tags: proxy, squid

i'm too beginner in squid. i want a way to remain anonymous over the net. i also want to be able to access the contents of the internet which are filtered. my Windows computer is beyond firewall (filtered). my server (CentOS 5) is not. for example, when i enter http://facebook.com in the browser url, it redirects to an intranet ip which tells me to avoid going to this site!
now i've installed squid on server and traffic is propagated through this server. but this redirection occurs. so still i can't open filtered sites.
what can i do? a friend of mine told that the only way is to use https. ie. the connection between browser (Firefox) and the server must use this protocol. is it right? and how can i do that?
what's your suggestion? i don't want necessarily to use squid. besides, https protocol gets banned or decreased in speed in my country sometimes. so i prefer the protocol remain http. i thought also about writing a code in client and server to transform, compress/decompress and packetize as hoax binary http packets to be sent as much speed and success as possible. but i'm not an expert in this context and now i prefer more straightforward ways.
i respect any help/info.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are located in Iran. I would suggest using TOR if you mainly access websites. The latest release works reasonably well in Iran. It also includes an option to obfuscate traffic so it is not easily detectable that you are using TOR.

See also this question: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/using-tor-in-iran-for-the-first-time-user-guide

A easy way to get the TOR package is using the autoresponder: https://www.torproject.org/projects/gettor.html
In case the website is blocked, it works as follows:

> Users can communicate with GetTor robot by sending messages via email.
>   Currently, the best known GetTor email address is gettor@torproject.org. 
>   This should be the most current stable GetTor robot as
>   it is operated by Tor Project.
>
> To ask for Tor Browser a user should send an email to GetTor robot
>   with one of the following options in the message body:
>
> ```
> windows: If the user needs Tor Browser for Windows.
> linux: If the user needs Tor Browser for Linux.
> osx: If the user needs Tor Browser for Mac OSX.
> ```

Comment: thanks. it was useful info about tor. but i've examined it before. it's too slow to be practically usable. then, when i've my own rapid server, why i must rely on a service which may be gone tomorrow and gets out of my access?
let's return to my question. can u answer and give me a way?
now i'm going to examine tor again, while i know that it's not as good as it's expected to be.
ur guess was right ;)

Comment: @hamidi HTTP is basically a cleartext protocol, I assume it gets filtered based on keywords. HTTPS is encrypted therefore it is harder to use this approach to filter it based on keywords. You could set up squid as a HTTPS proxy, then the connection between you and your server is encrypted using HTTPS, but you can still access normal HTTP sites. This does not resolve the speed reduction issue though.

Comment: it's better than nothing. but i don't know how to configure browser as well as squid for this purpose nor could i find the way in the internet.

Comment: besides, tor is not enough, even if it's fast, because i use download managers for downloading something like abode flash player, etc.